# invoke events in Form from class

Tags: c#

Hi is there a way to call the `buttonclick event` in a `Form` from a class which is unrelated to that form?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get hold of the button itself (e.g. by asking the `Form` for its `Controls` collection etc), you can call [`Button.PerformClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx). I'd say this is usually a bad idea though. If the form wants to let you perform a particular action, it should expose that as a public or internal method - and then call that method from the click handler.

Comment: yes, i think i am stuck with asking the Form for its Controls from the class. I can't even call the form though..

Comment: @belinq: So what information *do* you have, and why are you unable to do things the elegant way? Why can't you change the form? It would really help if you'd give us more context.

Answer (score 0):

The MVP pattern is designed for this separation. That's similar to what @Jon Skeet is stating in his response, but the executing code is separated from the class.

```
public class Presenter
{
     public void DoStuff() {};
}

public MyForm : Form
{
     private Presenter presenter;
     public MyForm()
     {
        presenter = new Presenter();
     }

     private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         presenter.DoStuff();
     }
}
```

Now you can call the click handler, but leave the form out of the invocation path.

Answer (score 0):

In the class declaration i have the method ButtonClick that will be called from the form on the ButtonClick event.

```
class Myclass
{
    public Myclass()
    {

    }

    public void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button Click");
    }
}
```

In the from you assign the event fro the button:

```
Myclass c= new Myclass();
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(c.ButtonClick);
```